# Python - Appending row number with reverse counter

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

I have yet another Python question. This one probably can be achieved with help of a loop, however I was looking for a leaner solution

Suppose that I have a data frame like this one:

[image]

I am looking for a code to generate column ID which is no more than a descending counter for when the value in column Sold changes - ie, for each Salesman I would like to have the ID column retrieving the number of days left until the sold value changes. 
For example, on date 01/01/2018, salesman Joe would be having ID = 2 because the signal changes in 2 days.

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Many thanks.
J

Comment: Please do not post data as an image. Also are your days guaranteed to be sequential within each Salesman?

Answer (score 1):

### Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2018', '1/7/2018').append(pd.date_range('1/1/2018', '1/7/2018'))),
    pd.Series(['Joe']*7 + ['Helen']*7),
    pd.Series([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]),
]).T
df.columns = ['date', 'salesman', 'sold']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

### Computation:

```
df['changes'] = df.groupby('salesman')['sold'].expanding().apply(lambda x: (np.diff(x) != 0).sum()).reset_index(drop = True)

df['id'] = df.groupby(['salesman', 'changes']).apply(lambda grp: pd.Series(len(grp) - grp.sort_values('date').reset_index().index)).reset_index(drop = True)

df.drop('changes', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

### Results:

```
>>> df


    date    salesman  sold  id
0   2018-01-01  Joe     1   2
1   2018-01-02  Joe     1   1
2   2018-01-03  Joe     0   4
3   2018-01-04  Joe     0   3
4   2018-01-05  Joe     0   2
5   2018-01-06  Joe     0   1
6   2018-01-07  Joe     1   1
7   2018-01-01  Helen   0   1
8   2018-01-02  Helen   1   2
9   2018-01-03  Helen   1   1
10  2018-01-04  Helen   0   1
11  2018-01-05  Helen   1   1
12  2018-01-06  Helen   0   2
13  2018-01-07  Helen   0   1
```

### Explanation:

create a `'changes'` column that increments every-time an individual salesperson's `'sold`' field changes. Then for each increment group (still grouped by salesperson), get the length of this group (which is equal to how subsequent rows of this value there are) and subtract from that value the index of each row, sorted by date. The result of that subtraction will be a series that descends from the length of the group to 1. Reset the index and merge back to your original dataframe. It's a bit of a confusing solution but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't really managed to get to the same result. Apart from Pandas, what other libraries are you using?

Comment: Can you give more insight into what went wrong? What was the error? I'm using pandas .22, numpy 1.14.12, and python 2.7. These are all pretty standard packages although a bit outdated.

Comment: Yes indeed, nothing out of the ordinary, I use them as well. The error occurs in the second line of the computation.

Comment: The error is quite long: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) . ;  ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1

Comment: It's hard for me to debug without seeing anything but it sounds like python is trying to assign 0 things to 1 placeholder. i.e. `df['id']` is not receiving a value from the RHS of the equal sign. try that line without assigning the value to `df['id']`. What you get from that should help you figure out your issue. Also try restarting your python and whatnot because my environment isn't throwing an error. And ensure you're using my set-up (for consistency's sake).